# LWC is not working as expected from Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-mobile-app

I am experiencing a problem about using an LWC component from within Salesforce Mobile App. Actually, the component is reading a file (from an upload action or an external url) and then is scanning that file to extract text information (it is like a lead scan). From desktop all it's working as expected, but when I try to use the same component (with the same apex code) from Salesforce Mobile App (both iOS and Android, i am using an iPhone 13 and a Samsung Galaxy s10e):

```
{"status":500, "body":{}, "headers": {}, "ok": false, "statusText": "Server Error", "errorType": "fetchResponse"}
```

I am unable to see errors or log debugs so it's very difficut to understand what is the real problem. Initially I was thinking about Heap Size or File Size but it seems to be another kind of problem cause from web it's all working perfectly!

The current Salesforce release I am working on is Spring '24.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you unable to see debug logs? Did you create a debug trace flag for the user that's logged in in the mobile app?